# How do you reduce this simple system diagram for the sake of doing algebraic manipulation?

Tags: control-system, signal-processing, diagram, laplace-transform

[image]

My guess is that since `H(s)` is parallel with `1(s)` we'd do `A(H - 1)`?  But this is my first diagram, so not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dotted node looks like it's A(s), and the node after H(s) looks like it's A(s)H(s), so A(s)H(s) - A(s) = A(s)(H(s) - 1) looks like the overall transfer function.

If you're not sure, any linear systems theory book should have a section on simplifying signal flow diagrams like this.